# AngularJS forEach iteration

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this JSON data, which is a return from Elasticsearch search results for an autocomplete query using ES's match_phrase_prefix query:

```
    "hits": {
   "total": 3,
   "max_score": 3.3071127,
   "hits": [
      {
         "_source": {
            "ymme": "bourne supremacy"
         }
      },
      {
         "_source": {
            "ymme": "bourne ultimatum"
         }
      },
      {
         "_source": {
            "ymme": "bourne idendity"
         }
      }
```

So what I'm trying to do is iterate through this to get the value of "ymme".

My current function in my controller for the autocomplete suggestions is like this:

```
//suggestions
$scope.getSuggestions = function(query) {
$scope.isSearching = true;
return searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return){
    var phrases = es_return.hits.hits;
    console.log(phrases);
    if (phrases) {
      return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases;
      console.log(suggestions)
    }
    else {
      $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
      $scope.noResults = true;
    }
    $scope.isSearching = false;
    },
    function(error) {
      console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
      $scope.isSearching = false;
    });
  };
```

What is happening here is that the suggestions display in the dropdown but the value of "ymme" (the actual suggestion) is not being passed to $scope.autocomplete.suggestions.

I need to iterate through the results and push the value of "ymme" to $scope.autocomplete.sugggestions, I've been looking at [angular.forEach](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.7/docs/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) but I'm not sure how to implement it since I'm dealing with a key, value pair that is in an object, which is in an object, which is an array, which is in yet another object:

```
"hits": {
   "hits": [
      {
         "_source": {
            "ymme": "bourne supremacy"
           }
         }
       ]
     }
```

Any ideas, suggestions?

**UPDATE**

```
//suggestions
$scope.getSuggestions = function(query) {
    $scope.isSearching = true;
    return searchService.getSuggestions(query).then(function(es_return) {
        var phrases = es_return.hits.hits;
        if (phrases) {
            return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases.map(function(item) {
                return item._source.ymme;
            })
        } else {
            $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = [];
            $scope.noResults = true;
        }
        $scope.isSearching = false;
    }, function(error) {
        console.log('ERROR: ', error.message);
        $scope.isSearching = false;
    });
};
```

**HTML dropwdown**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchTerms" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="{{ searchTerms }}" name="q" id="srch-term" uib-typeahead="query as query._source.ymme for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" typeahead-on-select="search($item)">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` like this:

```
return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases.map(function(item) {
    return item._source.ymme;
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" 
     ng-model="searchTerms" class="form-control input-md" 
     placeholder="{{ searchTerms }}" name="q" 
     id="srch-term" 
     <!-- change this -->
     uib-typeahead="query for query in getSuggestions($viewValue)" 
     typeahead-on-select="search($item)">
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I like this better than forEach, but how would I implement in $scope.getSuggestions above? Do I need to get rid of the if else statements or ....?

Comment: Just replace `return $scope.autocomplete.suggestions = phrases;` by the code in the answer and remove `console.log(suggestions)` it's unreached. you are welcome.

Comment: awesome! Ill have to implement this a bit later, I will accept once I get it working! thanks very much

Comment: sorry about that, got pulled away for a few days, got your answer working! thanks very much

Comment: any idea why the dropdown is displaying undefined again instead of the actual suggestions after I implemented your answer?

Comment: Did you change your object ?!

Comment: no everything is the same as far as I can see, Ill post the updated IF real quick.

Comment: I tried that change before and it didn't work. IT WORKS now though! I must of overlooked something - THANK YOU so much for your efforts!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to go with angular `forEach` ->

```
var res = [];
angular.forEach(hits.hits, function(src) {
   res.push(src._source.ymme);    
});
```